# How to disallow multiple folder in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I want to disallow robots from crawling any folder/subfolder.

I want to disallow the ff:

```
http://example.com/staging/
http://example.com/test/
```

And this is the code inside my robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /staging/
Disallow: /test/
```

Is this right? and will it work?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is right !
You have to add the command **Disallow** line by line to each path.

Like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /img/
Disallow: /docs/
```

A good trick is to use some [Robot.txt Generator](https://www.seoptimer.com/robots-txt-generator).
Another tip is [test your Robot.txt using this Google Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool)

Comment: ah so i need to add the Disallow: on the first line without any value on it.

Comment: Sorry. No you don't. Fixed on anwser.